# Drawing UI using density pixels

Tags: java, android, pixel, ui-design

I have a question about proper ways to draw UI, since I've learned what I know from the internet and by experimenting I often dont code the "proper" way, instead I do it my own way, not knowing if it will have consequenses that Im unaware of. So, Is it "wrong" to draw your UI using density pixels?

For Example:

```
canvas.drawText(bullets, this.getWidth() - 134 * dp, 32 * dp, paint);
```

I try to use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` as much as possible but sometimes I just need to use constants in my code to place stuff where I want it, is this ok as long as I use dp? or will this effect the layout on screens with different resolutions/performance? (Don't have anything except my own to run the game on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you perhaps mean the scale? This is a perfectly valid solution!

All of my android projects run with a "target resolution" and an "actual resolution", and all of my UI elements scale appropriately.

Let's say my target resolution is at 960x540 and my actual resolution is 1920x1080 (aka my Galaxy S3). That means my scale is 2. I draw an object at 50,50 and my handler will scale that from the target resolution to the actual resolution, putting it at 100,100 on the screen.

Comment: ah, thank you :) Just wanted to make sure before I get to deep in to it